# Download Custom CoreML Model and Load for Usage [Swift]

Tags: swift, machine-learning, coreml, mlmodel

I am creating an app based on Neural Network and the `CoreML` model size is of around 150MB. So, it's obvious that I can't ship it within the app.

To overcome this issue, I came to know about this [article](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreml/core_ml_api/downloading_and_compiling_a_model_on_the_user_s_device), mentioning that you can download and compile the `CoreML` model on device.

I did and I download on my device, but the problem is I cannot do the predictions as the original model. Like, the original model is taking `UIImage` as an input but the `MLModel` is `MLFeatureProvider`, can anyone address how can I do the type casting to my model and use it as original?

```
do {
    let compiledUrl = try MLModel.compileModel(at: modelUrl)
    let model = try MLModel(contentsOf: compiledUrl)
    debugPrint("Model compiled \(model.modelDescription)")
    //model.prediction(from: MLFeatureProvider) //Problem
    //It should be like this
    //guard let prediction = try? model.prediction(image: pixelBuffer!) else {
    //    return
    //}
} catch {
    debugPrint("Error while compiling \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

Comment: Hi am also working on same concept. I want to know how you make a CoreML model. I have done this with Python Turicreate.

Comment: The CoreModel are created by my team member! I am just using it in my project! @NeerajKumar

Comment: you can compress your model with CoreML2. Here's the link https://www.appcoda.com/coreml2/ @Sohil

Answer (score 2):

When you add an mlmodel file to your project, Xcode automatically generates a source file for you. That's why you were able to write `model.prediction(image: ...)` before.

If you compile your mlmodel at runtime then you don't have that special source file and you need to call the `MLModel` API yourself.

The easiest solution here is to add the mlmodel file to your project, copy-paste the automatically generated source file into a new source file, and use that with the mlmodel you compile at runtime. (After you've copied the generated source, you can remove the mlmodel again from your Xcode project.)

Also, if your model is 150MB, you may want to consider making a small version of it by choosing an architecture that is more suitable for mobile. (Not VGG16, which it seems you're currently using.)

Answer (score 0):

```
    guard let raterOutput = try? regressionModel.prediction(from: RegressorFeatureProviderInput(
        feature1: 3.4,
        feature2: 4.5))
        else {return 0}
    return Double(truncating: NSNumber(value:RegressorFeatureProviderOutput.init(features: raterOutput).isSaved))
```

Adding to what @Matthjis Hollemans said

Answer (score 0):

```
    let url = try! MLModel.compileModel(at: URL(fileURLWithPath: model))
    visionModel = try! VNCoreMLModel(for: MLModel(contentsOf: url))
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it's generally helpful to include an explanation of what it does. Otherwise your answer may be deleted.